# issues with joining query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting error in this query.
I don't know what's wrong in it.
Help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName,
count(*) as userTextCount FROM user LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.PostedAsId = user.UserID and
PostedAs = 'USER' and PostType = 'text',
count(*) as userMediaCount FROM user LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.PostedAsId = user.UserID and
PostedAs = 'USER' and PostType = 'media'
WHERE 1
GROUP BY Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName
```

ERROR:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'count(*) as userMediaCount FROM
user LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.PostedAsId = user.' at line 3
```

User table contains: Email, UserId, FirstName, LastName and posts table contains all the posts and I need to count posts by specific user.

Thanks.

Comment: Post more details, table strcure, error, data...

Comment: So this is invalid basic syntax for a lot of reasons.  Step one needs to be reading a reference on query syntax I think.

Comment: What do you have going on here buddy? This is all sorts of messed up.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use conditional count which can look something like this

```
SELECT Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostedAs = 'USER' and PostType = 'text' THEN 1 ELSE 0) userTextCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostedAs = 'USER' and PostType = 'media' THEN 1 ELSE 0) userMediaCount,
  FROM user u LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.PostedAsId = u.UserID 
 GROUP BY Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName
```

or

```
SELECT Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostType = 'text'  THEN 1 ELSE 0) userTextCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PostType = 'media' THEN 1 ELSE 0) userMediaCount,
  FROM user u LEFT JOIN posts p
    ON p.PostedAsId = u.UserID 
   AND p.PostedAs = 'USER'
 GROUP BY Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName
```

Comment: Wait are you telling me you know what OP was trying to accomplish?

Comment: @user2696691 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it would give you one line with the postType media and another with the post type text, you can just treat them in your business layer

```
SELECT Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName, PostType, count(PostType)
FROM user LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.PostedAsId = user.UserID 
WHERE PostedAs = 'USER' and PostType = 'media' OR  PostType = 'text'
GROUP BY Email, UserID, FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Email,
    UserID,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    PostedAs,
    PostType
FROM
    user
    LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.PostedAsId = user.UserID
WHERE
    PostedAs = 'USER'
    AND PostType IN ('text', 'media')
```

You should tell us what you need exactly. Maybe this query will be the beginning.